# Calling and splitting a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file called test.txt with the words "cat dog frog" in it. I need to split it so each word appears on a new line. Can someone help me please?

```
def get_tokens_from_file(test):
    with open("test.txt") as f:
```

Comment: Well, you've opened the file (assuming test.txt exists in your current working directory). Now try reading it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
           print(word)
```

Or if you want to flatten it:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    flat_list=[word for line in f for word in line.split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function does what you need.

The function reads each line of the source file (e.g. `test.txt`) and writes the words of that line as separate lines in the `ouput.txt` in the same directory.

The function works for any number of lines in your source data file.

```py
def get_tokens_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            tokens = line.split()
            with open("output.txt", 'a') as f:
                for word in tokens:
                    f.write(word + '\n')
```

Now you can run the function by the following command.

```bash
get_tokens_from_file("test.txt")
```

For example:

Assume the `test.txt` has the following lines:

```py
cat dog frog
bull zebra bee
cow horse snake
```

After you run the function, the result will be saved in the `output.txt` as follow:

```py
cat
dog
frog
bull
zebra
bee
cow
horse
snake
```